# Can an SQL Job Deletes itself after its end date?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, jobs

I have created a job which will sets up its start date and end date automatically with a dynamic value.

For example:

Job will run for eight days and at eighth day it needs to automatically deletes itself irrespective of its status.

Is there a way to code it while creating or scheduling ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Can an SQL Job Deletes itself after its end date?**
>
> I have created a job which will sets up its start date and end date
>   automatically with a dynamic value.
>
> Is there a way to code it while creating or scheduling ?

You can do this by using [sp_delete_job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188376.aspx) and dynamically creating applicable syntax and controlled logic to execute this for the ***dynamically created job name*** when date wise it needs to be deleted.

Since you are building the dynamic SQL Agent jobs and creating them with a start date and end date, you'd just put additional logic in to execute [**sp_delete_job**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188376.aspx) if the date is equal to day eight ***at the end of the job*** `WHERE @job_name = '<Dynamic Job Name>'`.

You could put the additional logic in ***at the beginning of the job*** to execute [**sp_delete_job**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188376.aspx) if the date is equal to day nine or the day after the eighth day `WHERE @job_name = '<Dynamic Job Name>'`.

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> sp_delete_job { [ @job_id = ] job_id | [ @job_name = ] 'job_name' } ,  
>      [ , [ @originating_server = ] 'server' ]   
>      [ , [ @delete_history = ] delete_history ]  
>      [ , [ @delete_unused_schedule = ] delete_unused_schedule ]
> ```
>
> <sub>[source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188376.aspx)</sub>

Since you control the logic that creates the dynamic SQL Agent jobs you should be able to test with additional logic that will delete the dynamic SQL Agent job and execute [**sp_delete_job**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188376.aspx) ***if the date is equal to*** a particular date (e.g. day eight or day nine).

It may be best to use logic that will execute [**sp_delete_job**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188376.aspx) ***if the date is greater than or equal to*** day eight or nine in case it doesn't run on the exact date due to system issues, etc. with logic such as: `WHERE Date >= CONVERT(datetime, 'YYYY-MM-DD' )`

> **Example**
>
> ```
> USE msdb ;  
> GO  
>
> EXEC sp_delete_job  
>     @job_name = N'NightlyBackups' ;  
> GO
> ```
>
> <sub>[source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188376.aspx)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Actually there is a simple way. You can add a jobstep in the very beginning and put the following code in the step

```
declare @job_id uniqueidentifier;
set @job_id=CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, $(ESCAPE_NONE(JOBID))); 

if getdate() > '2016-07-15 17:00:00' -- change to your preferred end time
begin
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id=@job_id, @delete_level=2; -- set auto deletion

    raiserror ('self deletion', 16, 1); -- cause the step failure
end
```

The job step is configured as [On Failure Action]="Quit the job reporting failure". 
I have tested it on both sql server 2012 and 2014. It works as expected, i.e the job will be self-deleted.

Comment: I copy & paste in a hurry and thus missing the first two lines, which I just added.